# Haskell - How can I make this lists into tuple function pair with all elements?

Tags: haskell

So i have

```
pair:: [a] -> [b] -> [(a,b)]
pair[] _ = []
pair(x:xs) (y:ys) = (x, y) : prod xs ys
```

But the result are only like the following:

```
>> pair [1,2] [3,4]
>> [(1,3),(2,4)]
```

How can I make this so it pairs like:

```
[(1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(2,4)]
```

Comment: If `setList` is a function that takes 3 arguments, how can `setList [1,2] [3,4]` even return anything printable? How can it return `[(1,3) (2,4)]`? And how can you give it two lists, if the second argument should be an Integer?

Comment: `setList` as defined definitely doesn't work, but we can provide a `setList` that behaves as expected. Well, assuming they still want tuples rather than lists. Making a best effort here.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs - see the new edit. the op seams to want `pair (x:xs) (y:ys) = [x,y] : pair xs ys` but I think the type checker will not like it if x is a a and y is a b ...

Comment: @Michael The new edit still has `(x,y) :`, not `[x,y] :`  (unless we are seeing different edits).

Comment: Yep, I copied the wrong answer in my file. I've made the change now, kind of typed the result up thinking it was setList, My bad!

Comment: still... what is `prod`? It's not a recursive call. Shouldn't it be `pair` instead?

Comment: @user32132321 I noticed that you have recently posted a number of questions with negative feedback. Before asking a new question, please consider what you have learnt from the last, such as: using [hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/), so as to avoid bad questions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the list applicative (or monad) instance:

```
λ> liftA2 (,) [1,2] [3,4]
[(1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(2,4)]
```

Or, equivalently,

```
f = do
   x <- [1,2]
   y <- [3,4]
   return (x,y)
```

You can also use a list comprehension:

```
[ (x,y) | x <- [1,3], y <- [2,4] ]
```

Comment: How you got here from the original question is way beyond me. Well done on that.

Comment: @DanielWagner I just looked at the expected result and made an educated guess. The rest of the question was confusing so I mostly ignored it... :)

Comment: Another somehow popular variant is `(,) <$> [1,2] <*> [2,4]`.

Comment: @chi and if banana brackets were a thing then we might be able to use `(| ([1,2] , [3,4]) |)`! Pretty sure that isn't better either...

Answer (score 1):

Although there is already a much more elegant answer, i think it is worthwhile to show how this would be achieved in a simple straightforward way. If you want to get all pairs, you obviously need to visit every element of one list for an element in the other.

```
pair :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a, b)]
pair [] _ = []
pair (x:xs) ys = pair' x ys ++ pair xs ys where
    pair' :: a -> [b] -> [(a, b)]
    pair' _ [] = []
    pair' x (y:ys) = (x,y) : pair' x ys
```

But of course using the `pair = liftA2 (,)` or `[1,3] >>= \x -> [2,4] >>= \y -> (x,y)` in its `do` notation or list comprehension notation is much better. Also `++` isn't what you normally want to do. So maybe you can build the lists as `pair'` would do, keep them in a list and then `concat` them.

```
concat $ map (\x -> map (\y -> (x,y)) ys) xs
```

Comment: You can improve the explicit recursion by letting `pair' _ [] = pair xs ys` so that the inefficient `++ pair xs ys` is no longer necessary. You can also remove the first argument from `pair'`, since `x` is already in scope.